# Event fired when hidden form is showed

Tags: c#, forms

I have 2 forms, and I want to hide one when the other one is CORRECTLY displayed. I've been using something like this code:

```
FormA form1 = new FormA();
FormB form2 = new FormB();

private void displayOne()
{
   form1.Show();
   form1.btn.Click += this.showForm2;
   form2.VisibleChanged += this.hideForm1;
}

private void hideForm1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.form2.Visible)
        this.form1.Hide();
}

private void showForm2 (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.form2.Show();
}
```

But using VisibleChanged hides form1 before form2 shows.

By the way, I can't use Shown event as forms are shown and hidden and not disposed. Shown is only fired on the first time Form is shown.

Answer (score 0):

By what you wrote I got that, you want to, get to show second form, after certain event, right?
then why don't you define it below your button onClick event?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        this.Hide();
        f.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();            
    }
```

Am I right?

Comment: As forms are really heavy, making Close and creating again a new form is not interesting; try to see this as singleton forms.
Moreover, ShowDialog is blocking call, and that's not pretended.
But thank you! :)

Comment: @Kensei, just wanted to help ;)

Comment: @Kensei Sry for double post, but That Form2 f is just Form2 instance, just for calling it out, or it makes programm more heavier?

Comment: the problem is swaping between form1 and form2; even if I just use `if (f == null) f = new Form2(); ` that will hide Form1 before Form2 is shown. The main problem is Form1 and 2 are really heavy, so showing it on a bit old computer makes it so horrible.